# How to get working Dialog API of OfficeJS API with Outlook 2016 desktop client

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I developed a outlook add-in which using OfficeJS API and want to implement OAuth within app, also
[API Documnetation](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/tutorial-api-requirement-sets.html) says Outlook 2016(Desktop) supports requirements set 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 & 1.4 but in my case it remains silent not even throws an error. 
While running working [dialog api sample for word add-in](https://github.com/richdizz/Word-Add-in-ColorPicker-Dialog) i am getting
**JavaScript run-time error:** `Unable to get property 'displayDialogAsync' of undefined or null reference`.

I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

Code I wrote to launch a dialog is below:

```
dialogTest() {
        const url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=....";
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { width: 15, height: 27, requireHTTPS: true }, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                // TODO: Handle error.
                return;
            }

            // Get the dialog and register event handlers.
            var dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.type !== Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived) {
                    // TODO: Handle unknown message.
                    return;
                }

                // Parse the message.
                var data = JSON.parse(asyncResult.message);
                console.log('Hello #Office365Dev', data.name);

                // TODO: Do something with the data.

                // We got our data, time to close the dialog.
                dialog.close();
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `ui` member of `Office.context` is not defined or `Office.js` is not loaded correctly. Try to review these first:

- Is `Office.js` javascript loaded correctly?
- Does [Office.initialize](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.initialize) callback well set and executed before you do something?
- What is your Outlook Desktop 2016 version?

**Edit:** discussing with Microsoft engineer on June 2016 (this is no official statement). The supported builds for `dialogAPI` is Office for Windows Desktop 2016 (build 16.0.6741.0000 or above). This may change.

- What is the result of this piece of code
  `var result = Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('DialogAPI', '1.4');`

Comment: Office JS loaded correctly also Office.initialize callback was executed properly because all other operation are working in place. I am calling the function `dialogTest()` on click of a button. My office desktop version is: **Word 2016 MSO (16.0.4266.1001)** I Installed **Office Professional Plus 2016** through ISO downloaded from Microsoft's official download page.

Comment: `var result = Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('DialogAPI', '1.1');` giving `false`

Comment: I think your version of Office is too old and does not bring the latest changes including the `dialogAPI` (see my updated answer). I think you should install using Click To Run to get all the latest features.

Comment: Yes you are right updated office version, it started working now. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Can anyone help me in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950678/word-add-in-stops-working-after-dialog-close-is-fired-office-js

Comment: @BenoitPatra Does this Dialog API works for Internet Explorer 11? login for web add-in in IE and Desktop is failing