# UI.displayDialogAsync() does not work in Outlook 2016 / Windows 10

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We build an Outloook Addin and are testing it across different platforms.

It works on all the browsers (IE 11, Edge, Chrome and Safari), but not in the Outlook 2016 on Windows 10.
We root cause it, looks like the problem is Office JS API [UI.displayDialogAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync?product=access) .
It does not open a dialog in Outlook 16 and the addin just hangs in there with the following progress message spinning forever,

> [Your Addin] is working onr your [Request]

The closest thing we found on the Internet is this [Stackflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259110/how-to-get-working-dialog-api-of-officejs-api-with-outlook-2016-desktop-client) in which the answer says
the oldest Outlook build that supports this API is 16.0.6741.0000.
We are using 16.0.9226.2114, so we meet the requirement.

Here are versions of OS/Outlook and Office JS we use in the test:

1. OS: Window 10 Home, Version 10.0.16299, x64
2. Outlook: 16.0.9226.2114, 32bit (Version 1804)
3. Office JS: 1.1.5-release-next.1 (We download the exact package from [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/tree/v1.1.5-release-next.1) and host it on our server)

Wonder is there any known issue of this API on Outlook 2016? Need some help here, thanks!

We have also been trying to debug Outlook 2016 using [F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) . 
But our addin cannot show up in the chooser page, no matter we launch the chooser before or after
we click on our addin. We have tried this on several windows 10 machines, but none of them work. Any suggestions that what we could possible miss here?

Comment: 1) Can you add the lines of code you are using for displayDialogAsync? 
2) Are you trying to access a web page that is not in the <AppDomains> section of your Manifest
3) Are you getting an error back from displayDialogAsync? (if so what) 
4) Hosting the Office.js from your server *should* work, but you may try going directly to: http://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.debug.js to be safe.
5) Instead of using the F12 tools, you can also attach a debugger (i.e. Visual Studio in script mode to the instance of IE)

Comment: If it is possible to share the add-in manifest, to see if we can get a local repro that would be good too. It is possible that the add-in just isn't being loaded at all. (though this probably isn't the case if you have already narrowed the issue down to display dialog) Can you load a Taskpane add-in (hosted on the same server) instead of an ExecuteFunction? to make sure IE/Outlook isn't haven't trouble reaching it.

Comment: We've been looking into the F12 Developer Issue, and we also repro not being able to attach to an ExecuteFunction. We're looking into it. For now though, we are able to attach with VisualStudio to the IE Instance. (you may need to enable script debugging in Internet Explorer Manually though) Tools->Internet Options -> Advanced. We were able to F12 debug on a taskpane. So if you can don't want to use VS, you could run your code in a taskpane app, and F12 debug it there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! We see <AppDomains> is the issue. We did not add the domain that the dialog is trying to open (a different domain than the addin itself that we have added).

Comment: The window opens now! But clicking on the windows throws us error which is not the case on IE 11. Checking them now.

Comment: Wonder do we know the version of IE engine that Outlook 2016 bases upon? Is it an version older than 11 or like a modified version of IE?

Comment: The IE engine used by Outlook 2016 is the same as what's installed (so IE 11 if that's what's installed). What difference or error are you seeing? Rather than the version, I wonder if the difference is due to OWA vs Outlook or because of the browser is embedded in the case of Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We do see navigator.userAgent gives us the same result in IE and the Dialog page popped from Outlook. (The dialog page loads in F12 Choose. Looks like, the only thing does not work there is ExecutionFile.) But unfortunately, the error of the Outlook dialog is a generic "Unspecific" error of a different site. The code of that site is compiled and it is hard to figure out what is actually throwing.

Comment: On the dialog popped by Outlook, we did a window.location.href in the F12 Developer Tool, and copied the exact URL to IE, and it worked fine there. We guess maybe, some global variables in the Outlook override those of IE and made the JS executed a different path intended for a different browser. Is there anything like that we are aware of?

Comment: Depending on the IE settings, it can load the web page under different x-ua compatibility. Especially if the site is hosted on an intranet and the intranet security settings are different in IE. (though knowing the exact error that is throwing would help here). You can try adding: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> to your html to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I see the site that the dialog is trying to load does have <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> in the HTML.

Comment: It's hard to know what could be the problem, without knowing a specific error. It could be something in that web page is not compatible within the dialog, (or there is a bug).

Comment: Found out where the error came from. History.pushState() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) of the page our dialog opens to throws in Outlook 2016, but works fine in IE11, Although we are not sure why. But we came up with a hack to work around this: have the dialog opens to a proxy HTML which redirects to the page we ultimately want after a short delay (100 millsecs). We are not sure why, but we found out that short delay is very critical to this solution. It will run into the same error without it.

Comment: So we move on. Everything works fine now in Outlook 2016, except the CSS is messed up there. But it works fine in IE11. We posted another question about it, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418251/css-is-changed-when-injected-into-outlook-2016-windows-client). Do you also have some insight about this issue?

Comment: The history object is not supported in add-ins. Both History.pushstate and replacestate have been nulled out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you had a similar issue to mine. For me adding the remote domain in the manifest resolved the case. Find and update the following section:

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://your.domain.com/</AppDomain>
  <AppDomain>https://auth.com/</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Proxy HTML works cause it's loading from your domain and still is viable solution.