# UI.displayDialogAsync() does not work in Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are building an Outlook Addin in which we call Office JS API [UI.displayDialogAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync?product=access) to open up a dialog to show an OAuth sign in page.

It works all well on Outlook 2016 (Windows). But does not work on 2013 (Windows). After the progressive message "[Your Addin] is working onr your [Request]" shows up, the dialog never came.

The version of the Outlook 2013 we are testing against is 15.0.5031.1000, which is higher than the minimal version that support Dialog API (according to this [doc](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/dialog-api-requirement-sets), the minimal is 15.0.4855.1000).

Moreover, [F12 developer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) which is the recommended tool for debugging Outlook addin cannot load ExecutionFunction (this is expected according to the discussion on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295403/ui-displaydialogasync-does-not-work-in-outlook-2016-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment87852384_50295403)).

We want to know, does Outlook 2013 actually support Dialog API? Is there any other way to debug this issue?

Comment: We have been able this issue that displayDialogAsync does not open up a dialog in ExecuteFunction extension point in Outlook 2013. We are doing further investigations to understand the issue better.
From my testing, displayDialogAsync does work with ShowTaskpane extension points. It would be helpful if you can try displayDialogAsync in ShowTaskpane to confirm that we have the same repro. Using ShowTaskpane is also a way to attach F12 developer tool.

Comment: You can also attach to ExecuteFunction add-in using Visual Studio by attaching to iexplore.exe. This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane  is for taskpane, but you can achieve the same result with ExecuteFunction if you attach to iexplorer.exe

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Our addin is indeed running in ExecutionFunction extension point, rather than the ShowTaskpane one.

Comment: We will see if we can repro that this API works in ShowTaskpane.

Comment: We put together a simplified addin (github.com/CodingFanSteve/outlookaddin/tree/master/taskpanel) to test displayDialogAsync() on taskpanel. Although it works on web, but the dialog does not work in either 2016 or 2013 on Windows. We replace some actual values in the manifest with '...'. Is there anything we are missing in the code?

Comment: We have another two questions, appreciate the help:

Comment: 1. Is there a way to instruct the manifest not to show an addin on Outlook 2013? The closest thing we found that is to specify the min Mailbox version. According to this doc (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook&version=v1.4), we need to do at least 1.5 to filter out 2013. However, that will also drop Outlook 2016 (MSI) for Windows which is not what we what. We want to know if there is a better way?

Comment: 2. Does Outlook Addin-ins Team have plan to fix the displayDialogAsync() API in ExecutionFunction on Outlook 2013 Windows?

Comment: We did further investigations and found that in our original repro, displayDialogAsync is not working when Windows still has outdated IE (IE9). In our repro, displayDialogAsync works correctly after updating to IE11. This is the link I used for the update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17621/internet-explorer-downloads Could you try updating IE to see if it resolves the displayDialog issue?

Comment: hmm, we actually have IE 11 installed. Could it be anything else?

Comment: I installed your sample. You are using arrow functions in your callback which is not supported in IE. Once I removed it, the dialog worked both in Outlook 2016 and in Outlook 2013.

Comment: To answer your first question, Outlook 2013 does not supported Version Overrides 1.1. Outlook 2016 does. So you could leave your 1.0 section blank, and then only have 1.1, that should prevent your add-in from showing up in Outlook 2013.

Comment: Thanks for the information! We replaced the arrow function with regular JS function and the dialog API is working in task panel in both 2013 and 2016 now. But still does not work in execution function in 2013

Comment: We used the app from the github link you mentioned, replaced the arrow functions with regular JS and changed the taskpane button to be an executefunction and the dialog does appear when the button is clicked. Could you share a manifest that reproduces the issue with execute function? Just to be sure, we hope you are calling event.completed() in the callback of displayDialog?

Comment: Quick question about the second comment. Does the way of debugging ExecuteFunction with Visual Studio work for Office 2013? I see this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane) mentions it only works for Office 2016.

Comment: No worries. We have this figured out. Also we got the dialog working in 2013. Thanks for all the previous help!